# FluentPage until doesn't work

Tags: java, testing, selenium, playframework

Consider this code:

```
 @Test
    public void newProject() throws Exception {
        drawer.group("Personal").newProject();   
        System.out.println(Predicates.alwaysTrue().apply(drawer.group("Personal")
          .hasProject("New project"))); //True
        Predicate p = drawer.group("Personal").hasProject("New project");
        dashboard.await().until(p);
}
```

The predicate I get from `drawer.group("Personal").hasProject("New project")` applies to `Predicates.alwaysTrue()`  but causes a `org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Timed out after 0 seconds`

Am I doing something from?

Comment: Well `drawer.group("Personal").hasProject("New project"))` doesn't return what you think it does then.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your default timeout is `0 seconds` which can cause your error.

You can specify a specific timeout using the `atMost()` method :

```
dashboard.await().atMost(3000).until(p);
```